# Efficient onDraw of ArrayList

Tags: android, arraylist, android-canvas, android-custom-view

I have a custom View on which I draw an ArrayList of Coordinates (which is a custom class just containing an x and y position). As more and more Coordinates are added to the ArrayList, the drawing noticeably slows down. I was wondering if there's a more efficient way to draw this ArrayList, or alternatively, if I can just add the one Coordinate that was added (because the ArrayList only changes one Coordinate between calls to invalidate).

Here are the relevant pieces of code:

```
public class CustomDraw extends View {
// member variables

public void updateLine() {
    // grab new coordinates for each measure

    if(measure1.isEmpty()) {
        measure1.add(new Coordinate(0, 0));
    } else {
        Coordinate last_coord = measure1.get(measure1.size() - 1);

        // calculations for south, north, east, and west

        if(south && east) {
            measure1.add(new Coordinate(last_coord.x + 3, last_coord.y + 3));
        } else if(south && west) {
            measure1.add(new Coordinate(last_coord.x - 3, last_coord.y + 3));
        } else if(north && east) {
            measure1.add(new Coordinate(last_coord.x + 3, last_coord.y - 3));
        } else if(north && west) {
            measure1.add(new Coordinate(last_coord.x - 3, last_coord.y - 3));
        }
    }

    if(draw) {
        dh.sleep(10);
    }
}


@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas c) {
    super.onDraw(c);
    Paint p = new Paint();
    p.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);

    p.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    c.drawPaint(p);
    p.setColor(Color.BLACK);

    switch(mSelected) {
    case Constants.MEASURE_1:
        for(int i = 0; i < measure1.size(); i++) {
            Coordinate coord = measure1.get(i);
            Log.d("MAAV", "drawing coord.x, coord.y: " + (coord.x) + ", " + (coord.y));
            c.drawRect(coord.x, coord.y, coord.x + 3, coord.y + 3, p);  
        }
        break;
    }

}

class DrawHandler extends Handler {

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        CustomDraw.this.updateLine();
        CustomDraw.this.invalidate();
    }

    public void sleep(long delayMillis) {
        this.removeMessages(0);
        sendMessageDelayed(obtainMessage(0), delayMillis);
    }
}
}
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are declaring `coord` each iteration of the loop. You don't need to do this and allocations of memory for objects can be expensive. Move that outside the loop and simply reuse the object. Also try commenting out the log calls or only log on each 10th item.

```
Coordinate coord;
for(int i = 0; i < measure1.size(); i++) {
   coord = measure1.get(i) 
   if (i%10==0)
       Log.d("MAAV", "drawing coord.x, coord.y: " + (coord.x) + ", " + (coord.y));
   c.drawRect(coord.x, coord.y, coord.x + 3, coord.y + 3, p);  
}
```

If these updates don't improve performance enough consider using OpenGL ES to do the drawing.

Answer (score 2):

Except from the improvement slayton suggested it may also be viable to use a HashSet instead of an ArrayList. This way you wont be able to add duplicate Coordinates. I don't know if you are doing this, but if you are this improvement will decrease iterations.

If you choose to do this you will need to implement an equals method to your Coordinate class, which Im sure you know. Or you might as well use java Point class, if your Coordinate just holds x and y positions.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I will definitely look into that.

Answer (score 1):

My approach would be to draw your canvas in a bitmap (or maybe use an extension of ImageView and use the backgroundDrawable) on each onDraw.  Add a field to your class to hold the latest new co-ordinate, then in subsequent onDraws, retrieve the bitmap and add the new co-ordinate only.  To reset, simply set the background bitmap again (or use View.setBackground as you are now).  I haven't tested this and it could use some enhancements but hopefully it gives you the idea and would be super efficient if, as you say, you are only adding one co-ordinate at a time.

```
public class CustomDraw extends View {

public Bitmap backgroundBitmap;
public Coordinate newCoordinate;

...   
...

@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas c) {

     // no super.onDraw as we are drawing everything

     Canvas backgroundCanvas = new Canvas(backgroundBitmap);

    ...
    ...

    // draw new co-ordinate to the background bitmap
    if (newCoordinate != null ){
         drawCoordinate(backgroundCanvas, newCoordinate);
         newCoordinate = null;
    }

    // draw the background bitmap to the view's canvas
    c.drawBitmap(backgroundBitmap, null, null);

    ...
    ...

}
```